# How much longer till I can ask again?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, reputation

I lost the privilege to ask questions on Stack Overflow about a week ago, due to some questions that I had posted that were just flat-out lazy, etc. I take full responsibility.

However, since that time, my reputation has gone up by over 10%, from edits and accepted answers. Isn't that enough to get it back? How much longer should I expect to wait?

Comment: "How much longer should I expect to wait?"  Until you fix your content.

Comment: The Question ban is not a timed ban, if you edit your existing questions such that they are upvoted your ban will end. Additionally, good answers may be taken into consideration but by far the most important thing is getting your questions to a good state

Comment: Looks like you're no longer banned. :)

Comment: @animuson, feel like weeping tears of joy! Thank you, oh thank you, oh thank you... :)

Comment: Seriously, Would you please put this in an answer so I can accept and upvote it?

Comment: Looks like people looked through your profile, thought your questions have improved and gave you a few upvotes, pushing you out of the ban. Remember you will still be very close to the threshold so make sure your next question is good

Comment: Please understand - the ban and the lifting of the ban are both **automatic** and are based on your questions and the votes they got. No individual here has caused the ban to disappear (and it could re-appear just as easily - you need to make sure your questions are suitable).

Comment: The ban is back...

Comment: I didn't ask any more questions, I just got down voted again on my old questions. What to do?